# How Do I Integrate Birst Single Sign on with Salesforce?

Tags: visualforce, integration, birst

I am trying to have this Birst web tab accessible to all Salesforce users, not just users who have Birst licenses. To do this I am trying to set up a Single Sign on between Birst and Salesforce.See: [Single Sign on for Birst](https://app2104.bws.birst.com/Help/BXE/setting_up_single_sign-on.htm)

I have followed the steps here to create a web tab in Salesforce:
[Adding a tab for Birst in Salesforce](https://app2104.bws.birst.com/Help/BXE/adding_a_tab_for_birst_in_salesforce.htm)

The user guide makes mention of using birst.SSOToken, birst.username, and birst.ssopassword: https://app2104.bws.birst.com/Help/BXE/sso_parameters.htm

Birst gives me the following Apex control code (I assumed I need to create a new Visualforce page and use this code somehow?):

```
<apex:page standardController="<object>" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:iframe height="<height>" width="<width>" src="https://app2101.bws.birst.com/AppExchangeSSO.aspx?serverurl={!$API.Partner_Server_URL_250}&sessionid={!$API.Session_ID}&birst.useSFDCEmailForBirstUsername=<true/false>&birst.hideDashboardNavigation=true&birst.hideDashboardPrompts=true&birst.module=dashboard&birst.spaceId=ed34a02f-06e2-4d66-a31c-986d2c8ee6ca&birst.dashboard=%20Executive%20Dashboard&birst.page=Executive%20Details"/>
</apex:page>
```

What is the best way to get Birst integrated into SFDC for users who do not have Birst licenses? How do I best call the SSO Token Generator through a post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to write a custom controller with a POST specifying the parameters, which include the space id, the sso password, and the user name of the account that will be used as the access user.

You can then make a Visualforce page with an action to send the request. Then you can make a link on the home page or tab for this Visualforce page. The parameters should pass correctly and open Birst in a new window. The request to the Token Generator will look something like:

req.setEndpoint('https://login.bws.birst.com/TokenGenerator.aspx'); // Server Url

The parameter passing will look something like:

req.setBody('birst.username=fakemail@yahoo.com&birst.ssopassword=fakepassword&birst.spaceId=fake-space-id'); // Request Parameters

The sso password and space ID is obtained in the Birst application.

Comment: I have still not figured out how to embedded tab in SFDC works with the parameter single sign on. If anyone has more insights or tips please share! :)